# How to have Thunderbird notify of new messages without having it in the launcher

Tags: 11.10, thunderbird, notification-area

Is there any way to make Thunderbird notify me of new messages without having it in the Unity Launcher. Just like some small notification in the upper bar or like the notification boxes that appear in the upper right corner and disappear after a couple of seconds.

Comment: `mail-notify` can take care of thunderbird no?

Comment: No, mail-notify does not correct this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to want to check email (POP3, IMPA4, social networking) **without** Thunderbird (or similar) being visible (or running).

I suggest you look at an applet like: **Popper**

*Popper – Feature-filled e-Mail notification applet for Ubuntu*

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/09/email-notification-in-ubuntu-popper/